# Is there Microsoft Transaction Server explorer on Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: vb6, mts

I need to "create packages and deploy components using MTS" for a higher national diploma course (BTEC). Can this be done with Windows 7 Ultimate and VB6?
I realize this feat may be outdated but I have no say in the syllabus and I can't find anything helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Installed packages live under Component Services: Component Services->Computers->My Computer->COM+ Applications

(Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) must be running)

[How To Create a 3-Tier Application Using VB, MTS, and SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186342)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the Component Services tool in Admin Tools.